# "Error: Failed to find 'ANDROID_HOME' environment variable." when deploying meteor with mupx

Tags: android, meteor, path, sdk

I want to deploy my meteor project in my VPS by using mupx. But when I run "sudo mupx deploy", I have an error (in linuxmint 17.2):

> Command failed with exit code 2 Error output: [Error: Failed to find
>   'ANDROID_HOME' environment variable. Try setting setting it
>   manually.Failed to find 'android' command in your 'PATH'. Try update
>   your 'PATH' to include path to valid SDK directory.]

I have already set my path in .bashrc:

```
export ANDROID_HOME=~/Android/Sdk
export PATH=${PATH}:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
```

And it works:

```
echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/home/noob/Android/Sdk/tools:/home/noob/Android/Sdk/platform-tools
```

When i run android command, the ANDROID SDK manager start correctly, that's why i don't understand the PATH error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same error message when trying to run `meteor run android --verbose`

What worked for me is setting ANDROID_HOME to an absolute path in ~/.bashrc like so:

```
export ANDROID_HOME='/home/noob/Android/Sdk'
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution: `meteor remove-platform android`

Source: https://github.com/arunoda/meteor-up/issues/730